# Gridview vith Checkboxes - make button inactive when some checkboxes are checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a Gridview binded with some data from SQL table. In the first column of GV I have CheckBoxes. Is it possible, to enable/disable button depending on which checkboxes were checked?

For better understanding here is an example;

In GV we have first column of cboxes, second column is ID and third column is Category.

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="MyCBox" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="category" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="category" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

We have two Buttons (Btn1 and Btn2)

```
<asp:Button ID="Btn1" runat="server" Text="btn1" OnClick="Btn1_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="Btn2" runat="server" Text="btn2" OnClick="Btn2_Click" />
```

Now...Let's say we have 2 categories (Cat1 and Cat2). When we select a checkbox and in that row Category value is Cat1, we have Btn1 enabled and Btn2 disabled;

```
Btn1.Enabled = true;
Btn2.Enabled = false;
```

Can this be done? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this assuming that you have only two categories

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:CheckBox ID="MyCBox" Text="Select Cat" AutoPostBack="true" ToolTip='<%#Bind("category") %>' OnCheckedChanged="MyCBox_CheckedChanged" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="category" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="category" />
</Columns>
```

Code behind event for the checkbox

```
protected void MyCBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if( ((CheckBox)sender).ToolTip == "cat1"
      { 
       Btn1.Enabled = true;
       Btn2.Enabled = false;
      }
    else 
      { 
       Btn1.Enabled = false;
       Btn2.Enabled = true;
      }          

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the buttons part of the grid?